# How to pass "Authorization: Bearer " to kafka-avro-producer

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I want to do something like this :

kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list [kafka-url] --topic test2 --property value.schema=[some-value-format] --property schema.registry.url=[schema-url] **--property Authorization: Bearer=$TOKEN**

Comment: That's not a valid property... I'm not sure that you can

Comment: yes, this is not valid. I checked the code base yesterday. io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient  always takes null :(

Comment: You can configure `USER_INFO` though, I think